# How to inherit and add Action menu in odoo

Tags: odoo, enhanced-ecommerce, odoo-14

I have created and upgraded a custom module successfully. My module especially inherits & adds new fields in Products for e-commerce.
Now I am facing an issue that could not add an action button at the action button dropdown in the website setting->product->select product ..
this is how I extend and add a field

```
from odoo import models, fields, API
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'
   isOffered = fields.Boolean('isOffered')
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGKYPtAeP7k)

Or:

To add the button inside the action button we need to add the code below.

```
 <act_window name="You Action"
        id="update_state_action"
        res_model="update.state"
        binding_model="sale.order"
        binding_views="form"
        view_mode="form"
        target="new"
    />
```

Where binding_model is the model to bind the action to. and res_model is like a wizard that performs an action

Check [this](https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/add-new-button-inside-action-menu-in-odoo-13) for details